# Setting value on dynamic radio button with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an issue setting the value in a dynamically created radiobutton group to an object. 
When the object specified in ng-model is not null, the radio button isnt checked, and clicking any radio doesnt trigger the attached $watch. However, if object in ng-model is null when loading, the $watch seems to work fine. Now, if i change the value of ng-model to a string it works fine, the issue is that i need the entire object. Basically each model is a question and when the question is changed in the UI the entire model object is sent to a webservice.

Data (Value is set - doesnt work)

```
{
    "__type": "RadioQuestion:#MyProject.Model.Entities",
    "Id": "ff3234ba-40fe-43e3-9457-ea5e3b5ae5a7",
    "Question": "Question goes here",
    "RangeMaxText": "Very likely",
    "RangeMinText": "Not Likely",
    "Title": "Question headline",
    "DefaultValue": {
        "Id": "id-for-no-value",
        "Name": "Nej"
    },
    "PossibleValues": [
        {
            "Id": "id-for-yes-value",
            "Name": "Yes"
        },
        {
            "Id": "id-for-no-value",
            "Name": "No"
        }
    ],
    "Question": "Hows it hanging?",
    "Value": {
        "Id": "id-for-no-value",
        "Name": "Nej"
    }
}
```

Markup

```
<h4>{{question.Question}}</h4>
<label data-ng-repeat="pValue in question.PossibleValues" for="{{question.Id}}-{{pValue.Id}}">
    <input
        id="{{question.Id}}-{{pValue.Id}}"
        name="radio-for-{{question.Id}}"
        type="radio"
        data-ng-value="pValue"
        data-ng-model="question.Value" />
        {{pValue.Name}}
</label>
```

Data (Value is null - works)

```
{
    "__type": "RadioQuestion:#MyProject.Model.Entities",
    "Id": "ff3234ba-40fe-43e3-9457-ea5e3b5ae5a7",
    "Question": "Question goes here",
    "RangeMaxText": "Very likely",
    "RangeMinText": "Not Likely",
    "Title": "Question headline",
    "DefaultValue": {
        "Id": "id-for-no-value",
        "Name": "Nej"
    },
    "PossibleValues": [
        {
            "Id": "id-for-yes-value",
            "Name": "Yes"
        },
        {
            "Id": "id-for-no-value",
            "Name": "No"
        }
    ],
    "Question": "Hows it hanging?",
    "Value": null
}
```

This is the watch function:

```
this.$scope.questions.forEach((question) => {
    this.$scope.$watch(
        () => { return question; },
        (newVal, oldVal) => this.updateQuestion(newVal, oldVal),
        true
    );
});
```

Comment: do you import ng-controller Question as question? Could you console.log(question) ?

Comment: Can you log in console inside $watch function if it changes?

Comment: Hi cyan. Yes i can log in the $watch function just fine - and it outputs the question with the updated Value. I just found out, that if setting a Value on load, when clicking the other option then it triggers the $watch, and from here on the $watch works fine. So it looks like the ng-model is set correct, but the radio just isnt checked.

Comment: set data-ng-value="pValue.Id"

Comment: Hi cyan, unfortuntely setting data-ng-value="pValue.Id" isn't working becuase then Value will be a string instead of an object with { id, name } which is what is expected serverside when saving the answer.

Comment: can you provide with code with $watch?

Comment: Watch function added in the bottom.

Comment: maybe wrapping call to rest, or after success around $apply would make you sure that all $watches are checked. Use $apply as close to event as you can.

Comment: Hi cyan, im not sure what you mean with "maybe wrapping call to rest, or after success around $apply would make you sure that all $watches are checked", can you elaborate? The watch is already applied as narrow as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found out that i had to use the Id property to both ng-value and ng-model of the Value object to make this work

```
<label data-ng-repeat="pValue in question.PossibleValues" for="{{question.Id}}-{{pValue.Id}}">
    <input class="field radio"
        id="{{question.Id}}-{{pValue.Id}}"
        name="radio-for-{{question.Id}}"
        type="radio"
        data-ng-value="pValue.Id"
        data-ng-model="question.Value.Id" />
    {{pValue.Name}}
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dynamically generated elements are not an option in AngularJS 1.2 from what I know. Should normally work in 1.3.

Comment: Hi Dragos, i am using Angular 1.3.8.